# ScrollMagic loop - scene duration the same as the video duration that's part of the scene

Tags: javascript, loops, video, duration, scrollmagic

I have a loop of scenes with videos that play on scroll (loop because it's integrated with WordPress ACF Flexible fields). I'm using ScrollMagic for that (and GSAP but that doesn't apply here).

What I'm trying to do is to make the duration of the whole scene same as duration of the video of the scene (on the front-end there'll be a presentation with different videos). I tried simply `video.duration`, but it beahvaes in a weird way: sometimes it works, sometimes not. Is there a solution for this?
Here is my code:

```
const startVideoFullScreenOnScrollFunction = () => {

const startVideoFullScreenOnScroll = document.querySelectorAll('.video-fullscreen-text-on-scroll');

for (let i = 0; i < startVideoFullScreenOnScroll.length; i += 1) {
  if (typeof (startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i]) !== 'undefined' && startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i] != null) {

    const controllerVideoFullScreenOnScroll = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    const videoFullScreen = startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i].querySelector('video');
    const textsOnVideo = startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i].querySelectorAll('.video-fullscreen-text-on-scroll__copy');

    const timelineVideoFullScreenOnScroll = new TimelineMax();

    // fade in & fade out text
    for (let j = 0; j < textsOnVideo.length; j += 1) {
      timelineVideoFullScreenOnScroll
        .to(textsOnVideo[j], {
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 3,
        })
        .to(textsOnVideo[j], {
          opacity: 0,
          duration: 3,
        });
    }

    // ScrollMagic scene
    let sceneVideoFullScreenOnScroll = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: ???,
        triggerElement: startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i],
        triggerHook: 0
      })
      .setTween(timelineVideoFullScreenOnScroll)
      .setPin(startVideoFullScreenOnScroll[i])
      .addTo(controllerVideoFullScreenOnScroll);

    let scrollpos = 0;
    let startpos = 0;

    sceneVideoFullScreenOnScroll.on('update', e => {

      startpos = e.startPos / 1000;
      scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 1000;

      if (scrollpos >= startpos) {
        videoFullScreen.currentTime = scrollpos - startpos;
      };
    });
  }
}
```

}

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thank you for your input - I'm in the process of fully migrating to GSAP. However in this case I'd like to finish what I started (if that's possible). Could you please help me with my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really used ScrollMagic. ScrollTrigger is much easier to use if you ask me so I recommend just migrating to using it instead. I think you'll be surprised by how easy it is :)

Comment: Ok, thank you - I'll try that. So basically I'll be able to recreate every functionality that ScrollMagic offers, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! And more.